# Dynamically populating ACF field works with select - but not with select2

Tags: javascript, wordpress, jquery-select2, advanced-custom-fields

I have a select field *$("#country")* in a ACF form on Wordpress backend which triggers the values for a second select field *$("#city")*. It's a typical Country/City relationship with custom values.

The script is enqueued, the change event is triggered and the second select gets populated with success using this code:

```
var cities = {
    "Spain": [
        "Madrid",
        "Barcelona"
        ],
    "Portugal": [
        "Lisboa",
        "Oporto"
    ]
}

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#country').change(function () {
        loadCities($(this).find("option:selected").val());
    }).change();
});

function loadCities(country) {
    $('#city').empty();

    cities[country].forEach(function(city) {
        $('#city').append("<option value='"+city+"'>"+city+"</option>");
    });
}
```

As the list of cities is quite long, I want to use **select2 instead of select**. Here the changed *loadCities* function:

```
function loadCities(country) {
    $('#city').empty();

    var data = [{id: "", text: ""}];
    cities[country].forEach(function(city) {
        data.push({id: city, text: city});
    });

    $('#city').select2({
        data: data,
        placeholder: "Select a city"
    }).trigger('change');
}
```

The problem is that the options (=cities) don't show up as expected in the select2 list. But they seem to be appended, checking their existence with jquery shows them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing you can dynamically append options using the data attribute even for a multi dimensional json array of objects. **But do not initialize the select box twice!**

```
$("#country").select2({ data: data.keys });
```

Instead destroy it and init with your values, you can also try with change event.

```
$("#country").select2('destroy').empty().select2({ data: data.keys });
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thanks, that works. So the key is to no initialize select2 twice and destroy it before filling it with new values.